# Generating function of a discrete variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, generating-functions

Suppose that $G_X$ is the generating function of a discrete variable $X$. I have to determine the generating function of $nX$.
I don’t know how to proceed.

Comment: Since you are using "$n$" in $nX$ and $n+X$, you should use a different index for the sum in the generating function, say $k$ (i.e. $G_X(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=k) t^k$).

Answer (score 2):

We start with

$$
G_X(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X = k)t^k
$$

First let $Y = nX$, where $n \geq 1$ is an integer.  Then $P(Y = nk) = P(X = k)$, which gives us

\begin{align}
G_Y(t) & = \sum_{j=0}^\infty P(Y = j)t^j \\
       & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(Y = nk)t^{nk} \qquad j = nk \\
       & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X = k)(t^n)^k \\
       & = G_X(t^n)
\end{align}

where we can make the identification $j = nk$ because no other possibilities for $j$ are permitted; $Y = nX$ can only take on values that are multiples of $n$.

Can you do something similar with $Z = n+X$?

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot.

Comment: for Z=n+X, I have to set j=n+k?

Comment: @earth99: Yes.  You don't have to change the sum in the answer you deleted; you only need to recognize that $P(X = k) = 0$ for $k < 0$, so $\sum_{k=-n}^{-1} P(X = k)t^{n+k} = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!:)